# Windows portable executable resources - looking for embedded manifests structure description

Tags: resources, manifest, portable-executable

i'm looking for a description of the manifest embedded in PE files. I know it's an XML file, what i'm looking for is a description of its structure and/or fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,
This then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375635(v=VS.85).aspx